# String concatenation query returning wrong results

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata

Trying to automate this part of Teradata query:

```
c."currency" = CONCAT('FOO_', '2021') -- c."currency" = 'FOO_2021'
```

trying to replace the `2021` with the currently selected fiscal-year, so it is not hard-coded:

```
c."currency" = CONCAT('FOO_', c."fiscal-year")
```

c."fiscal-year" is of type `VARCHAR(20)`.

**Problem** - the first query returns about 5 times more results than the second one, so I am doing something wrong, I guess. Tried with `TO_CHAR(c."fiscal-year")` and so on, did not succeed.

Comment: Perhaps the current fiscal year is not 2021.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - it is. I checked the results. Only one unique result and it was 2021.

Comment: Does c."fiscal year" only contain "2021" or is there a leading space or something else that makes it different?

Comment: "fiscal-year" is probably a numeric value, you get an automatic type cast which adds leading spaces, `trim(c."fiscal-year")` --> `'FOO_' || trim(c."fiscal-year")`

Comment: @Duston - no leading space. Tried this one - `c."currency" = CONCAT('FOO_', TRIM(c."fiscal-year"))`, same number of rows.

Comment: @dnoeth - tried this one, same old 5 times less rows. Even tried this one - `c."currency" = TRIM('FOO_'|| TRIM(c."fiscal-year"))`, still not successful.

Comment: What's returned by `select distinct char2hexint(TRIM(c."fiscal-year"))`? Maybe there's some trailing character which only looks like a space.

Comment: @dnoeth - will check it in 6 days and will let you know :)

Comment: @dnoeth - it returns 2 values - `32303230` and `32303231`, which I guess stand for 2021 and 2020.

Comment: Yep, 2020/2021. `'FOO_' || trim(c."fiscal-year")` results in `'FOO_2021'`. There must be something else.

Comment: @dnoeth - any idea what can it be, since I am really not changing anything else... It is a big query indeed, could it be that it calculates half of the query concerning `c."fiscal-year"` before the other half or something like this?

Comment: Compare Explains of both selects, check the step with the where-conditions